# How to redirect all website request to https://www in laravel?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to force all request to https://www . Code is working properly and send request to https://www but the problem is it load only homepage of webiste other shows 404 error.
My Htaccess code if-

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=302,L]
  </IfModule>
```

My url is :- https://www.makemyfoam.com/contact
if i use :- https://www.makemyfoam.com/index.php/contact
then it work properly

Comment: Hey vikas! Have you tried adding `URL::forceScheme('https');` to your routes file?

Comment: Yes. But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the mine one and it's working properly (it doesn't have the "www" redirect):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```